# Holomorphic function on $\mathbb C^n$

Tags: complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables

I take $F$ from $\Omega\subset \mathbb C^n$ to $\mathbb C^n$ to be a holomorphic function such that
$$| \det(J_F)|\leq 1,$$
where $J_F$ is the Jacobian matrix of $F$.

My question: Is there  any classification of functions of this type?

Comment: What kind of classification do you expect?  Up to $\mathrm{Diff}(\Omega)$? There are a lot of such functions: take *e.g.* any triangular nonlinear pertubation of a triangular linear application $L$ with $|\det(L)|\leq1$.

Comment: I am interested to understand the type of the functions satisfying this inequality, then any classification will be useful.Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function has constant Jacobian by Liouville. Then it is
map of Jacobian 1 composed with a homothety or its differential is degenerate everywhere. The constant Jacobian biholomorphisms are subject of much research, see for example

*Rosay, Jean-Pierre,
Automorphisms of Cn, a survey of Andersén-Lempert theory and applications. Complex geometric analysis in Pohang (1997), 131–145,
Contemp. Math., 222, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, RI, 1999.*

Comment: Verbisty Be careful, $F$ is defined on $\Omega$, not on the whole space $\mathbb{C}^n$. So Liouville theorem does not apply.

Comment: sorry, i misread the question

Comment: Misha Verbitsky, thanks a lot, I find the reference that you mentioned very interseting, I didn't know it before.